# Create and publish a new post every Monday, listing the post titles and links to the posts published during the previous week

Tags: php, functions, hooks, wp-insert-post, callbacks

Newbie to Wordpress and PHP!

Every Monday, my task is to create one post (let's call it *summary*) in a custom post-type called "news".

In *summary*, the "contents" field will be a list of titles and links to all posts (with post-type "post") published in the previous week.

Currently, I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Check if today is Monday, if so, continue to 2
2. Check if *summary* is already posted, by checking if the page exists (I am setting the *summary*'s permalink such that it ends with the date it is published)
3. If it does not exist, proceed to publish *summary* (defined for now as `$page`).

**My Issue**

- The `$page` is not published on Monday.

**Other Info**

- *Summary* (`$page`) is still static content (not retriveing information from posts in the previous week), as I am still testing how to publish something periodically.
- I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897758/how-to-set-post-permalink-slug-in-wordpress-using-wp-insert-post) that *post_name sets the slug*, thus I set `'post_name' => date('YMD')`,though to be honest I'm not sure if I'm doing it right...In the post edit page for *summary*, I would usually manually enter like so:

[image]

My code below:

```
function publish_news() {
    if (date('N') != 1) {
        return;

    } else { 
        $today = date( 'Ymd' );
        $page_exists = get_page_by_path('/news/' + $today);
        
        $page = array(
            'post_title' => 'My post!!!',
            'post_name' => date('Ymd');
            'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
            'post_status' => 'draft',
            'post_type' => 'news',
        );

        if ($page_exists != null) {
            return;
        } else {
            wp_insert_post($page);
        }
    
    }
}

add_action('init','publish_news');
```